# Display inline block causing a strange line to appear

Tags: html, css

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/qXZFW/10/

On the menu on the left it seems the display inline block is causing a line to appear at the start of each piece of text

```
.nav-sprite {
  background: url('http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg');
display: inline-block;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 15px;
margin-right: 12px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If I remove it, the layout changes and calls apart. Can anyone please explain why this is happening and how I resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `text-decoration: none;` to `.nav li a` - this will solve the problem. It's just the underlining of the link you see.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you are using an anchor tag by default has the property "text-decoration:underline", use the following rule to solve this.

```
.nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```